# rgl toggle sharedMouse retrospectively

Tags: r, rgl

rgl allows multiple subplots with `mfrow3d()`. These subscenes can respond to the mouse collectively with `mfrow3d(..., sharedMouse=TRUE)`.

However, I would like to toggle the shared mouse behavior on/off *after* the the subplots have been drawn. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it by modifying the `par3d("listeners")` property of each subscene.  That property lists the ids of the subscenes that will "hear" mouse events.

For example:

```
library(rgl)
ids <- mfrow3d(1, 2, sharedMouse = TRUE)
shade3d(cube3d(col = "red"))
next3d()
shade3d(tetrahedron3d(col = "blue"))

# This makes the the tetrahedron on the right ignore mouse actions in the cube
# on the left. The cube will still respond to actions on the right.

par3d(listeners = ids[1], subscene = ids[1])

# This stops the cube from responding, so the two subscenes 
# are now independent

par3d(listeners = ids[2], subscene = ids[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

@user2554330 pointed me to set `par3d(listeners=...)` for each subscene, and illustrated it with an example to turn off the shared mouse behavior for two subscenes.

In the case of multiple subscenes, it is handy to use a loop/apply:

```r
library(rgl)

shared_mouse_on <- function(ids) {
  lapply(ids, function(id) {
    par3d(listeners = ids, subscene = id)
  })
}

shared_mouse_off <- function(ids) {
  lapply(subscene_ids, function(id) {
    id_listeners <- par3d("listeners", subscene = id)
    # remove any listeners that are in 'ids', for this subscene 
    #   (except this subscene's listener itself)
    id_listeners <- id_listeners[ !(id_listeners %in% setdiff(ids, id) ) ]
    par3d(listeners = id_listeners, subscene = id)
  })
}
```